# Grails isDirty() not working with associations

Tags: grails

in my app, I'm updating an object Voucher which has 1:1 association to Patient entity. In my controller, I call "voucherInstance.properties = params" to bind the new values. But when I change the Patient in Voucher (not saving it yet), and then I call isDirty('patient'), which IMO should return true in this case, it actually returns false.

Also, the getPersistentValue('patient') returns the changed value, not the original one. Do I undestand these methods correctly?

Thanks,
Lojza

In my controller class:

```
def update() {
   Voucher voucherInstance = voucherService.get(id)
   voucherInstance.properties = params // patient is being sent from view by params.patient.id
   voucherService.update(voucherInstance)
}
```

In my VoucherService class:

```
public Voucher update(Voucher voucher) {
   if (voucher.isDirty('patient')) {  // returns false
      // do something
      Patient oldPatient = voucher.getPersistentValue('patient') // returns the updated patient
   }
   voucher.save(flush: true)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your (changed) instance isn't saved before calling `isDirty`? [getPersistentValue()](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/getPersistentValue.html) should give you the persisted/unchanged value. If the persisted and the changed value are equal, `isDirty` must be `false`. Do you have some code for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more googling and found one solution, though not a good one: http://stuff4j.blogspot.com/2011/05/i-encountered-few-times-strange.html

```
def update() {
   Voucher voucherInstance = voucherService.get(id)
   voucherInstance.patient = null
   voucherInstance.properties = params // patient is being sent from view by params.patient.id
   voucherService.update(voucherInstance)
}
```

This seems to work. But I have to explicitly set all associations to null before I can update them.

Answer (score 2):

The correct use here should be `voucherInstance.patient.isDirty`. The parameterized version of `isDirty` is meant for bean fields iirc.

Comment: This returns the same result as the method.

Comment: Are you changing patient or making a new one? If it's a new one it won't be dirty, as it hasn't been in the DB yet.

If it's one you're updating, then I'm not sure actually.

Comment: Nope, I'm updating it. You can see in my first post as I added some codes to it.